# why can't I create a clone of my character in a module script?

Tags: lua, roblox

In a module script, in a function that works when entering the game, I create a condition

```
if skin == "Soulless" and not skinModels:FindFirstChild("Soulless") then
        local oldCharacter = player.Character
        local newCharacter = oldCharacter:Clone()
        newCharacter.Name = "Soulless"
        newCharacter.Parent = skinModels
    end
```

I am getting an error: attempt to index nil with 'Name'
Based on which I realized that the script does not want to clone my character

I tried to create a function in a regular script with the same condition and call it in a modular script and it doesn't help. I tried to create a function with a condition in a local script and call it through this modular script - it doesn't work either. If anyone knows, please explain what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the main problem is that when the player loads into the game, a character can't appear instantly; it takes some time for it to spawn. So instead of writting something like you did I would do like this instead:

```lua
if skin == "Soulless" and not skinModels:FindFirstChild("Soulless") then
        local Check = false
        local CharacterEvent = player.CharacterAppearanceLoaded:Connect(function(chr)
            Check = true
        end) 
        repeat
            task.wait()
        until Check == true  
        CharacterEvent:Disconnect()     
        local oldCharacter = player.Character
        local newCharacter = oldCharacter:Clone()
        newCharacter.Name = "Soulless"
        newCharacter.Parent = skinModels
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your function does not work for me. Where the Repeat cycle is, it lasts forever for me

Comment: If it does that then the problem is not in the part of the code you gave us. In fact it's probably because player is nil

Answer (score 0):

Characters have the `Archivable` property set to false hence they can't be cloned without setting it to true first.